# GGPlot's scale_color_manual shows error

Tags: r, ggplot2

There are two questions with similar problems, but they do not work for this, so please don't mark as dublicate.

I got a normal ggplot with one set of values and 3 horizontal lines, but when I use scale_colour_manual it returns

> Error in c(`Total Tweets` = "#f04546", Mean = "#3591d1", `Standard
>   Deviation` = "#62c76b") :    unused arguments (`Total Tweets` =
>   "#f04546", Mean = "#3591d1", `Standard Deviation` = "#62c76b")

```
Data<-data.frame("Date"=as.Date(16200:16499),"Total"=rnorm(300,4500,50))
Mean<-mean(Data$Total)
SD1<-Mean-sd(Data$Total)
SD2<-Mean+sd(Data$Total)

TotalDay <- ggplot(data = Data, aes(x=Date, y=Total,colour=Legend)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=Total, colour="Total Tweets")) 

TotalDay + ggtitle("Tweets per Day") +labs(x="Date",y="Tweets") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color="#666666", face="bold", size=18, hjust=0)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(color="#666666", face="bold", size=13)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept =Mean,colour="Mean")) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept =(SD1), 
                 colour="Standard Deviation"))+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept =(SD2), 
                 colour="Standard Deviation"))

TotalDay + scale_color_manual(name="Legend",
                              values=c("Total Tweets"="#f04546","Mean"="#3591d1","Standard Deviation"="#62c76b"))
```

So just the last line does not work.
I use the packages (I don't know if that makes a difference):

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(Ryacas)
library(quantmod)
library(data.table)
library(tm)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)
```

Comment: I don't get an error when I run your code. (I'm using ggplot2 2.2.0 and R 3.3.2)

Comment: I don't get an error either. Did you accidentally overwrite `c` with a different function? If you run just `c`, you should get `function (...)  .Primitive("c")`. If you get something different, then the issue is almost certainly that you have a different function saved in place of `c`

Comment: Yes, I used c before as a function, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second step you don't actually re-assign the results of the plotting back to `TotalDay`, so when you get to the `scale_color_manual` you've no lines there to actually construct a legend for.

```
Data<-data.frame("Date"=as.Date(16200:16499),"Total"=rnorm(300,4500,50))
Mean<-mean(Data$Total)
SD1<-Mean-sd(Data$Total)
SD2<-Mean+sd(Data$Total)

TotalDay <- ggplot(data = Data, aes(x=Date, y=Total,colour=Legend)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=Total, colour="Total Tweets")) 

TotalDay <- TotalDay + ggtitle("Tweets per Day") +labs(x="Date",y="Tweets") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color="#666666", face="bold", size=18, hjust=0)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(color="#666666", face="bold", size=13)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept =Mean,colour="Mean")) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept =(SD1), 
                 colour="Standard Deviation"))+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept =(SD2), 
                 colour="Standard Deviation"))

TotalDay + scale_color_manual(name="Legend",
                              values=c("Total Tweets"="#f04546","Mean"="#3591d1","Standard Deviation"="#62c76b"))
```

[image]

Comment: My main problem was in the comments (I used c as a function before), but  your answer helped me afterwards as well, thank you!